# Is it illegal to post a picture of you and your ex best friend on social media without her consent?

Tags: social-media, consent

We went through a fight and me and her are no longer best friends. I posted a TikTok about her and me no longer being friends. It says “dear ex best friend” there is nothing inappropriate or rude. The pictures are of me and her. She did not give consent. She is telling me I need to take it down. And that it is illegal. Can I get in trouble for not taking it down?

Comment: Take it down, which is the decent thing to do in the situation. You can lose your account if you don’t (I know you can on Facebook) because that’s what the company can do. Legal consequences are possible; she might get a court to force you to take down the image, depending on where you are.

Comment: Jurisdiction matters and needs to be specified, I believe the answer for this will be different in different countries.

Answer (score 2):

If someone else took the picture, you have to have their permission to make any copies including posting it online. The [TikTok EULA](https://www.tiktok.com/legal/terms-of-use?lang=en#terms-us) (US version) allows you to post material that you have the right to post (e.g. a photograph that you took; the photo is not a "private photo") as long as it isn't in violation of the various prohibitions in §5 (intimidating, pornographic, or material that TikTok judged to be objectionable). Nothing in the EULA requires you to obtain permission to post pictures of an individual. There is no US law requiring permission to post a picture of a person.